# How to extract data from Java web application?

Tags: java, networking, scripting, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

I need to extract data from a Java web application. To be specific I am looking to extract real time stock data from yahoo market tracker. Can anyone please suggest any method?

Comment: And your current code looks like?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can extract the data from Yahoo Market Tracker. Even if you can, you might not be allowed to - I can't see any obvious terms & conditions/licensing. I *think* (although I could be wrong, anyone got better info?) that you'll need to pay to get access to an API providing near realtime market data.

There is a HTTP-based Yahoo Stock Quote API you could use to get prices, [described here](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm). Very simple, returns a comma-separated list of attributes for one or more stock symbols, for example:

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT&f=snd1l1yr

It might not be realtime enough, but it might be the best you can do for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glorious HTTP protocol to do that. Use any language you are comfortable with (Java, C#, VB.NET, python, ruby, php) and **crawl** the website you are trying to get information from.

Comment: i can crawl the html code but how do i crawl for the data that is being display in the form of java app??

Answer (score 0):

> I need to extract data from a Java web
>   application

From your standpoint, the fact that it is a Java Webapp or a PHP-one or static html pages doesn't change anything.  It is not because Java is backing the webapp that suddenly you get a "Java-way" to extract the info.

Now in some cases there are APIs provided allowing you to interact with the data present on the website: but once again the fact that the Webapp is a Java one or not bears no importance.

Comment: but incase of normal static html site i can scrap and go through the code to take info but incase of a java app tht cannot be done.